# Limit request to Xing API

Tags: api, rest, social-networking

I'm developing an application that requests to get resource from Xing. However, XING will return limit error (**403 RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED**) when I request reach limit. But I cannot find any information about the limitation of XING; such as API Key limitation, token limitation...

Please help me to handle this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer follow link bellow:

> https://dev.xing.com/docs/rate_limits

cheer!

Answer (score 1):

About the rate limit for Xing dev, check below :

**Consumer rate limits:**

1200 requests / 60 seconds (Ban time: 1 minute)
30000 requests / 60 minutes (Ban time: 5 minutes)
300000 requests / 24 hours (Ban time: 20 minutes)
Note: For test keys the consumer rate limits are equal to the user rate limits (see below).

**User rate limits:**

120 requests / 60 seconds (Ban time: 1 minute)
1200 requests / 60 minutes (Ban time: 5 minutes)
15000 requests / 24 hours (Ban time: 20 minutes)

For more information , check [enter link description here](https://dev.xing.com/docs/rate_limits)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this this page is useful for your reference:
https://dev.xing.com/docs/error_responses